# How can you play a game that requires an 15 sided die with a 6 sided die

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How can you play a game that requires a 15 sided die with a 6 sided die?

Comment: Depends on the game, die, and what you're looking for. It's not unfeasible to just reroll if you get a value not on the six-sided die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roll the 6-sided die once, discarding any 6s until you get a roll that's not a 6.

Then roll the 6-sided die again, and halve it (divide by 2, rounding up).

The formula
$$
3\times(\text{first roll}) - (\text{halved second roll}) + 1
$$
gives a result that is equally distributed from 1 to 15.